# DispatcherServlet is not getting called?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"     
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"  
version="2.4">
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```xml
<html>
<body>
<form action="add"> 
    <input type="text" name="one"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="two"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome-servlet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ashish.springMVC" />

<bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> 
</beans>
```

**controller**

```
package com.ashish.springMVC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Java4sController {

@RequestMapping("/*")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
 System.out.println("hello....");
 String message =  "Welcome to Java4s.com Spring MVC 3.2.x Sessions";
 message += "<br>You Did it....!";

 return new ModelAndView("welcomePage.jsp", "welcomeMessage", message);
 }//ModelAndView closed

 }
```

**welcomePage**

```xml
<html>
<body>
<font face="verdana" size="2">
   ${welcomeMessage}
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to run this but the code is accessing DispatcherServlet, behaving like JSP.
I tried executing this but it gives 404- no resource /add found error. Please suggests some edit to make it run correctly.

Comment: Evidently you've taken this code from http://www.java4s.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-spring-mvc-3-2-hello-world-example-in-eclipse/ .  Go back to that page and check for differences between your code and the code on that page.

Comment: i tried again but same issue..Am i missing something ?

Comment: What do you mean by you 'tried again'?  Have you made any changes to your code?  If so, edit your question to include them.

Comment: Dear...am a beginner , learning how to setup spring MVC, trying to write hello world of MVC. My expectation was to get bit help to run a simple MVC program. Anyway thanks... !!

Comment: Please show the full error message, and if possible a stack trace. It may help to understand if the problem is DispatcherServlet not hit, controller not found or view not found...

Answer (score 0):

The way you about it is to analyze the problem scenario and try to minimize the problem area

- First check if the request is reaching the controller.
- if the request is not reaching the controller then you need to figure out what could be the reason like is the welcome-servlet.xml placed in the correct location
- If the request is reaching the controller then check if there is something going wrong inside the `helloWorld()` for things like you returning welcomePage.jsp in 
  `new ModelAndView("welcomePage.jsp", "welcomeMessage", message);` which should be `new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "welcomeMessage", message);` as the internalResourceViewResolver just needs the name.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it addressed your question

Comment: definitely....i have a reputation below 15 which doesn't allow to upvote..., Accepted ur answer !!